# Which method to use to set up a dynamic port mapper

Tags: apache, networking, routes, tcp, mapping

I have a web app which relies on a number of back end services, and I would like to be able to dynamically switch between different instances of these services. So the thinking was to create an intermediate app which listens on some ports and redirects traffic as required.

If I was dealing with pure HTTP I would look at doing this with Apache and proxy_pass, which would be ideal (fast, reconfigureable with no down time), but it's not just HTTP traffic, which is why I'm stuck

Any nudges in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a software (e.g. Vyatta, pfSense, etc.) or hardware router and put some NAT rules in places?

A pretty neat open source app I sometimes use when I quickly need to forward some ports, etc. to do some testing is TcpTunnel: http://www.vakuumverpackt.de/tcptunnel/

Comment: As I mentioned you can just use a free software router like Vyatta and run it on a VM, that's not gonna cost you anything and takes an hour to set up.
Alternatively you could easily script TcpTunnel to change port forwards, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could just configure Apache to dynamically listen on a bunch of ports (seems to have an upper limit on that, about 100 on my system) and then use mod_rewrite to dynamically map those ports to your content. You could also use dynamic hosts, written out in Perl, but then you would also need to include all your other configuration that was the same for each instance.

```
# Use Perl to write out many Listen directives
LoadModule perl_module  libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so

<Perl>

  # The Dynamic Ports are those from 49152 through 65535
  # On the machines I tested 100 seems to be the upper limit
  # Apache 2 seems to have issues starting (memory?) when the number
  # is too high. Once the server has started, there does not seem
  # to be a performance hit for having a large number of ports open

  # Starting at 50000 for cleanliness
  my $lower_port = 50000;
  my $max_ports_to_use = 100;


  my $upper_port = $lower_port + $max_ports_to_use;

  foreach my $port ($lower_port .. $upper_port) {

    # Listen on a specific port number
    push @Listen, $port;

  };

</Perl>


# if we are in the range of dynamic ports
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} >49152
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} <65535
  # serve up content on that port number
  RewriteRule (.*) /dynamic_sites/%{SERVER_PORT}/$1
```